# How javascript function body can be an object instead of a series of lines of code?

Tags: javascript, function, javascript-objects

I've been reviewing how an old AngularJS solution works and in one of the controllers I've found the following code:

```js
Array.prototype.update = function (newArray) {
    loop: for (var newIndex1 = 0; newIndex1 < newArray.length; newIndex1++) {
        var newItem = newArray[newIndex1];
        for (var oldIndex1 = 0; oldIndex1 < this.length; oldIndex1++)
            if (this[oldIndex1].Id === newItem.Id)
                continue loop;
        this.push(newItem);
    }
    loop1: for (var oldIndex2 = 0; oldIndex2 < this.length; oldIndex2++) {
        var oldItem = this[oldIndex2];
        for (var newIndex2 = 0; newIndex2 < newArray.length; newIndex2++) {
            if (newArray[newIndex2].Id === oldItem.Id)
                continue loop1;
        }
        this.splice(oldIndex2, 1);
    }
};
```

Basically, an "update" function is added to standard Javascript Array that does some adding and removal of the items.

But how come the function body that is defined in curly braces is not a series of lines of javascript code (expressions), but is a javascript object with two properties `loop` and `loop1`.

As this seems to be valid javascript, where can I read about this style of definition to learn what is the logic of execution of this?

Comment: `But how come the function body that is defined in curly braces is not a series of lines of javascript` it is. `but is a javascript object with two properties loop and loop1.` it isn't. `loop` and `loop1` are labels.

Comment: What you have is a couple of [labelled block statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/block#labelled_block_statement)s

Comment: @tkausl and James thank you both. Didn't know about the existence of labeled block statements.

Answer (score 0):

In the function code above, `loop` and `loop1` are [labeled block statements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/block#labelled_block_statement), as kindly noted by [James](https://stackoverflow.com/users/535480/james) in the comments to the original question.